# cant find getApplicatinContent android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

i have this code its adpter java code

```
    package com.example.adopt_pet_app;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.orhanobut.dialogplus.DialogPlus;
import com.orhanobut.dialogplus.ViewHolder;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Pets_info,myadapter.myviewholder>
{
    public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Pets_info> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Pets_info model)
    {
    holder.petname.setText(model.getPname());
    holder.pettype.setText(model.getPtype());
    holder.petage.setText(model.getPage());
    holder.petgender.setText(model.getPgender());
    holder.petlocation.setText(model.getPlpcation());
    holder.petdes.setText(model.getPdes());
    Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(model.getPimg()).into(holder.img);


    holder.ask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final DialogPlus dialogPlus=DialogPlus.newDialog(holder.ask.getContext())
                    .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.aprovedialog))
                    .setExpanded(true,1500)
                    .create();
            dialogPlus.show();


            View myview=dialogPlus.getHolderView();
            EditText name=myview.findViewById(R.id.unameadopt);
            EditText phone=myview.findViewById(R.id.uphoneadopt);
            EditText email=myview.findViewById(R.id.usubmitadopt);
            Button ask=myview.findViewById(R.id.askforadoptbn);





          //  name.setText(model.getAd_name());
          //  phone.setText(model.getAd_phone());
            //email.setText(model.getAd_Email());
           // dialogPlus.show();


            //



            ask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("name",name.getText().toString());
                    map.put("phone",phone.getText().toString());
                    map.put("email",email.getText().toString());


                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ask_for_Adopt").push()
                            .setValue(map)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    name.setText("");
                                    phone.setText("");
                                    email.setText("");
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Thank you",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                            })
                           .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                               }
                           });





                }
            });





            //


        }
    });




}


@NonNull
@Override
public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow,parent,false);
    return new myviewholder(view);
}

class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ImageButton img;
    Button ask;
    TextView petname,pettype,petage,petgender,petlocation,petdes;
    public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        img=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        petname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        pettype=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView23);
        petage=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        petgender=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView27);
        petlocation=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
        petdes=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView31);
        ask=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.askforadoptbn);





    }
}
```

}

Im working in adopter java file everything was fine but when i try to add this code red come to getApplication content

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContent(),"Thank you",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image]

can anyone tell me how i can solve this  i want insert the data into
my firebase if this way wrong is there another way i do insert code but in the adpter ???  thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Change your code from

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContent,"Thank you",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(holder.ask.getContext(),"Thank you",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: still the same  problem it say can not resolve method

Comment: If the myadapter class receive a context as param in the constructor, then you can use that context instead.

Comment: Don't post code image, could you post myadapter.java code?

Comment: There's no ```getContext``` or ```getApplicationContext``` in an adapter. Like @SonTruong said, you need to define context in your constructor then you can use it.

Comment: @SonTruong yes i edit and put all myadapter code there

Comment: @كايوتشان Glad to hear that. Happy coding =))